# How to split two times?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a long string with some data… I need to split it by `&` and then each of it by `=` and create from it pair like `key: value` from the last split… Is it possible to do without big loops? Something like:

```
video_data = video_data.split('&')
video_data = {key:value for value.split('=') in video_data.iteritems()}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're actually after: `urlparse.parse_qs`

Comment: don't reuse the same variable name for different purposes. It makes code harder to read.

Comment: where does `video_data` come from? Is it from an url? Is it percent-encoded? Could there be duplicates (several equal keys)?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you're trying to parse a query string. Python already has a method for this, and that will also handle multiple values for keys and automatically create a dict of key->list of values for you:

```
from urlparse import parse_qs

s = 'a=3&b=5&a=4'
qs = parse_qs(s)
# {'a': ['3', '4'], 'b': ['5']}
```

As noted by [J.F. Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4279/j-f-sebastian) in comments:

Note: it does more than just splits on & and = e.g :

```
parse_qs("a=%21&b=urlencoded")
# {'a': ['!'], 'b': ['urlencoded']}
```

Comment: Note: it does *more* than just splits on `&` and `=` e.g., `parse_qs("a=%21&b=urlencoded")` -> `{'a': ['!'], 'b': ['urlencoded']}` It might or might not what the OP wants. We don't know.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian That's a good point - I've moved it into the answer in case comments get cleaned up.... Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Either [`urlparse.parse_qs()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs) or [`urlparse.parse_qsl()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qsl) would do this job for you, better, faster and more robustly:

```
>>> example = 'foo=bar&ham=eggs&answer=42'
>>> from urlparse import parse_qs, parse_qsl
>>> parse_qs(example)
{'answer': ['42'], 'foo': ['bar'], 'ham': ['eggs']}
>>> parse_qsl(example)
[('foo', 'bar'), ('ham', 'eggs'), ('answer', '42')]
>>> dict(parse_qsl(example))
{'answer': '42', 'foo': 'bar', 'ham': 'eggs'}
```

Use one or the other depending on how much you need to support keys appearing multiple times in the query string.

But you really wanted to do this yourself with a dict comprehension, you need to nest the `.split()` call into a tuple:

```
video_data = {key: value for item in video_data.split('&') for key, value in (item.split('='),)}
```

but the same parse is just easier without a dict comprehension; using a generator expression instead to produce a sequence of key-value pairs for the `dict()` factory instead:

```
video_data = dict(item.split('=') for item in video_data.split('&'))
```

Demo:

```
>>> example = 'foo=bar&ham=eggs&answer=42'
>>> {key: value for item in example.split('&') for key, value in (item.split('='),)}
{'answer': '42', 'foo': 'bar', 'ham': 'eggs'}
>>> dict(item.split('=') for item in example.split('&'))
{'answer': '42', 'foo': 'bar', 'ham': 'eggs'}
```

Comment: Or: `dict(keyval.split('=') for keyval in example.split('&'))` instead of sticking with the dict-comp

Comment: if you expect a single key, value pair then you could use: `[pair.partition('=')[::2] for pair in data.split('&')]`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I'd prefer `pair.split('=', 1)` instead of the stride slice, but yes.

Comment: `partition()` *always* returns the same number of items. `.split()` may return less.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: That is a good point. But that *could* be an error, in which case you'd want an exception. :-)